# Is there anyway to get source code for .so file?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu-16.04, symbols, name-mangling

Is there any way to extract the code source Ubuntu 16
from a `.so` file?

I used this command:

```
readelf -Ws /root/file.so
```

But I am looking for a way to understand how each function works.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Maybe? It depends if that library is open-source or not. A lot of the things on Ubuntu are, but not necessarily all, and not necessarily in an easy to find place.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. Once you compile your code there is no trace of it left in the binary, only machine code.

People may reccommend you decompilers but those just aren't perfectly reliable and when they execute they will produce the source code that SHOULD have the same effect as the original code.